# Vba web scraping

Tags: vba

Olá, estou com um problema ao realizar um web scrapping no site "https://esaj.tjsp.jus.br/cpopg/open.do"

No VBA consigo abrir o site e tudo mais e até inserir os valores que eu quero, o problema é que tem um dropdown "Pesquisar por", que ao selecionar pelo navegador no dropdown "Documento da parte", parece que ele habilita um script que então habilita o input Número do processo. Coisa que pelo vba, ele não habilita, então ele insere o valor, mas parece que só como se fosse no placeholder.

Então em resumo, o que eu quero fazer é o seguinte:

1. Abrir esse site no VBA ("https://esaj.tjsp.jus.br/cpopg/open.do")

## DADOS DA PESQUISA

2. Foro => "Todos os foros da lista abaixo"
3. Pesquisar por (Dropdown) => "Documento da parte"
4. Número do processo => "Algum cnpj válido"
5. Pesquisar.Click()

Comment: Favor inserir o código que você utiliza.

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia Juny espero que o código abaixo ajude

Primeiro passo é configurar as referências.

no IDE do VBA vá em **Ferramentas** > **Referências** em seguida marque as opções: *Microsoft Internet Controls* e *Microsoft HTML Object Library*

```
Sub Bot()
    Dim objIE As Object
    Dim aEle As HTMLLinkElement

    Dim result As String
    Dim CNPJ As String
    Dim URL As String

    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
    CNPJ = "123456789" 'pode apontar para uma célula
    URL = "https://esaj.tjsp.jus.br/cpopg/open.do" 'pode apontar para uma célula
    objIE.Visible = True

    objIE.navigate URL

    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    objIE.document.all.Item("cbPesquisa").selectedIndex = 2 'posição do item documento da parte
    objIE.document.all.Item("cbPesquisa").FireEvent ("onchange") 'atualiza seleção
    objIE.document.all.Item("campo_DOCPARTE").Value = CNPJ 'CNPJ
    objIE.document.all.Item("pbEnviar").Click 'click

    CNPJ = ""
    URL = ""
    Set objIE = Nothing
End Sub
```